# Ionic run app on device exit code 1

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I've spent all day trying to fix this error, i have no idea why this happens. i can build both iOS and android, but when i try to run on device, both iOS and android Exit code 1, here the log

---

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 21.515 secs
Built the following apk(s): 
        /Users/Jose/Desktop/smarket/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Jose/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
Skipping build...

Built the following apk(s): 
        /Users/Jose/Desktop/smarket/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Using apk: /Users/Jose/Desktop/smarket/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Package name: io.ionic.starter
Error: Failed to install apk to device: [  0%] /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
[  2%] /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
...
[ 99%] /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
[100%] /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
/Users/Jose/Desktop/smarket/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-deb

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android --device (exit code 1).
```

Comment: do you see your device if you run `adb devices` ? Is a version of your app already installed on your device?